# Parabolic Cylinder Coordinates

Tags: calculus

If you were on a desert island, how would you derive [parabolic cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylindrical_coordinates) from scratch - no memorizing formulas or memorizing extraneous terms in constant surfaces. I just can't see how these things naturally fall out!

Comment: You have a very cool question here, but you should think of a way of making it more clear and specific. Like, "What is the intuition behind parabolic cylindrical coordinates?" and include the definition, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, I don't see any difference between what I said & what you said, except that my way of phrasing it forces the responder to take seriously the question of intuition & not resort to referring to crazy confocal constant surfaces with terms I'll instantly forget because they have no apparent justification. Penalizing me for my very functional use of language, a language that I've had many times to use with professors after phrasing things your way (to get a direct answer) is very very strange.

Comment: Also I've linked to the wiki page with the definitions. I purposely didn't post them so the person responding would have every impetus to use logic to remember the formulas & not resort to looking at them, again a consequence of my functional use of language, but apparently that was lost on you guys unfortunately.

Comment: This is the kind of nonsense that scares people away, I mean wow...

Comment: I saw three votes to close on your question and I knew why; the math stackexchange culture puts a lot of emphasis on certain words, and writing the same thing two different ways can make a huge difference. I think your question is great, I love having discovered parabolic coordinates through your question, and I want your question to succeed. Yes, the culture can be silly, and I'm sorry for your stress. I shouldn't have voted to close just because I knew it would close, and I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks man, it's a shame people would stifle a bit of inquiry based on Victorian nonsense, but repentance is a worthy trait ;) I just can't make sense of the transformations with all the bells & whistles attached to them, I've been trying for well over a month at moments & this thread was the result of giving up.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question that should not have been closed. I have voted to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks man, but you are setting a dangerous precedent - there are 10 other coordinate systems in which simple separability of common PDE's is both allowed & useful ;)

Comment: Hey guys I don't know if you get notified but I posted a really succinct derivation of this coordinate system in a comment below if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at this picture from the wikipage

[image: Confocal parabolas]

and figured out that confocal parabolas means they all share the same focus. So first thing to work out is where does the focus of a parabola lie, since I don't remember that formula.

So take the following parabola with coordinates $y=ax^2$. A focal point for this parabola means that when a ray comes in from infinity, parallel with its symmetry axis, then the reflected ray goes through the focal point. That's what I can remember about focal points.

A ray coming from infinity has cartesian equation $x=x_0$. It hits the parabola in the point $(x_0,ax_0^2)$ where the tangent has a directional vector $(1,2ax_0)$. A normal vector to this tangent is $(-2ax_0,1)$. The angle between the incoming ray and this normal and the outgoing ray and this normal has to be the same, thus the scalar products of the vectors has to be the same,

$$(0,1)\cdot(-2ax_0,1) = \sqrt{1+4a^2x_0^2}\cos\alpha = (p,q)\cdot(-2ax_0,1)$$

provided that $(p,q)$ is normalized, i.e. $p^2+q^2=1$.

With a bit of algebra, you can then work out that a directional vector of the outgoing ray is

$$(4ax_0,4a^2x_0^2-1)$$

From this, it is easy to find a parametric equation for the outgoing ray

$$\begin{cases}x=x_0+\lambda (4ax_0) \\ y=ax_0^2+\lambda (4a^2x_0^2-1)\end{cases}$$

The focal point is the intersection of that ray with the symmetry axis of the parabola and has coordinates $(0,f)$ with $f$ being after some work

$$f=\frac{1}{4a}$$

Thus, the parabola $y=ax^2$ has this focal point. I want now to construct parabolas that all have the same focal point, and I'll choose that point to be $(0,0)$. All I have to do is shift my parabola accordingly so that I have.

$$y=ax^2-\frac{1}{4a}$$

Let's say that $a>0$, then I'll keep track of the parabolas pointing down with another parameter $b>0$ and they have equation

$$y=-bx^2+\frac{1}{4b}$$

Allow me now a slight abuse of notation, because I want to replace $a\to a/2$ and $b\to b/2$ to have nicer equations

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(ax^2-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

and

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(-bx^2+\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

Our work is almost done. A point that lies on both parabolas for certain parameter values $(a,b)$ must have

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(ax^2-\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-bx^2+\frac{1}{b}\right)$$

or after some work

$$x^2=\frac{1}{ab}$$

and plugging this in in one of the formulas for the parabolas we also have

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

Introducing a final change of parameters $\tau^2=1/b$ and $\sigma^2=1/a$ we obtain

$$x=\sigma\tau \; \text{ and } \; y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\tau^2-\sigma^2\right) $$

which are indeed the same equations as on the wikipage. The corresponding equations for the parabolas are

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}x^2-\sigma^2\right)$$

and

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{\tau^2}x^2+\tau^2\right)$$

Comment: That is a sheerly phenomenal response, I'll go through it in detail soon enough, thanks!

Comment: As fantastic as this derivation is I am not smart enough to remember it, but there is an extremely simple way to derive parabolic cylinder coordinates that I've found. Just think of the transformation $f(z) = z^2 = (u + iv)^2$ in the complex plane, you get $(u^2-v^2)+i(2uv) = x + iy$! Obviously since we're trying to derive coordinates on parabolas a transformation like $f(z) = z^2$ applying here makes sense intuitively, but to get the actual coordinates you just get rid of the $2$'s by defining $f$ as $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}z^2$, then $z = z$ is obvious since they're cylinders, wow!

Comment: If you play around with it a bit, for example setting $y = 0$ or just setting $u$ or $v$ constant in $y$ then subbing into $x$ etc... the graphs start to make a lot more sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice catch with the complex transformation. In fact, complex analysis is often handy when trying to solve the Laplace equation. It's related to the theory of harmonic functions, Cauchy-Riemann equations, etc... I wouldn't be surprised if your transformation is somehow natural in that context.

Comment: Yeah you're right, there's a whole theory of deriving two-dimensional coordinate systems using conformal transformations & many of them are rotated etc... to give three-dimensional systems. I don't really know any of the details but am working towards getting there. There's a book by Willatzen that goes over everything, though they leave out the intuitive derivations of the coordinate systems unfortunately.