# Parabolic Coordinates Radius

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given Cartesian $(x,y,z)$, Spherical $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and parabolic $(\varepsilon , \eta , \phi )$, where

$$\varepsilon = r + z = r(1 + \cos(\theta)) \\\eta = r - z = r(1 - \cos( \theta ) ) \\ \phi = \phi $$

why is it obvious, looking at the pictures

[image]

[image]

that $x$ and $y$ contain a term of the form $\sqrt{ \varepsilon \eta }$ as the radius in

$$x = \sqrt{ \varepsilon \eta } \cos (\phi) \\ y = \sqrt{ \varepsilon \eta } \sin (\phi) \\ z = \frac{\varepsilon \ - \eta}{2}$$

and is my picture right or is it backwards?